# How to show this convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n$ be random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$, respectively. Suppose that $(X_n)_n$ converges to an invertible matrix $A$ in probability and that $(X_nY_n)_n$ converges to a random variable $Z$ in distribution. How can I show that $(Y_n)_n$ converges to $A^{-1}Z$ in distribution? I guess the idea is to apply the Slutsky's theorem. The point is that it is not guaranteed that $(X_n)_n$ is invertible everywhere.

Comment: @fGDu94 Could you please give me a hint how to come to this result using the Slutsky's theorem?

Comment: @fGDu94 As I said, $X_n^{-1}(\omega)$ does not exists for any $n$ and $\omega$..

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz Yes. $Z$ is a vector.

Comment: My suggestion is to consider the case of real valued random variables. I think the proof for the general case would be almost identical to this special case.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks for the advice! I tried a bit but it is not easy neither..